# Retrofit 2 add Header - Logging interceptor

Tags: android, logging, header, retrofit2, interceptor

I'm adding a Header to a get request - the server-side doesn't receive the header. I'm using `addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())`.The code:

```
        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @NotNull
                    @Override
                    public okhttp3.Response intercept(@NotNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request originalRequest = chain.request();
                        Request newRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                                .addHeader("Header","123")
                                .build();
                        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
                    }
                })
                .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                .build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("URL")
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();

        retrofit2.Call<String> call = apiRetrofitInterface.getString("URL");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<String> call, retrofit2.Response<String> response) {
                 // 
            }
```

Interface Code:

```
public interface ApiRetrofitInterface {

    @GET
    Call <String> getString(@Url String url);
}
```

Is it possible that the header is in the Logging Interceptor but the server doesn't receive it?

```
 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> GET "MY URL"
 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Header: 123
 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> END GET
 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 400 Bad Request "MY URL" (137ms)
 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: X-Powered-By: Express
 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS
 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Length: 39
 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: ETag: W/"27-Gy6wj20Vfpjmp7p+PeGaPrL9u2U"
 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Date: Sun, 31 May 2020 21:53:29 GMT
 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Connection: keep-alive
 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- END HTTP
```

Comment: "the server-side doesn't receive the header" -- how are you determining this? Have you tried using a tool like Charles Proxy to inspect the actual communications, to see if the header is in the request?

Comment: @CommonsWare - My partner works on the server-side. I'll forward your message. does my code seem ok?

Answer (score 0):

If the header not in w3cschool protocol，It may be removed by the Firewall what the Gateway your data transported used.

So use the header key in http protocol.

hope to help you

Comment: How exatly do I use the header in the HTTP protocol?

Comment: I means  invoke the  addHeader(key,value) the key need access the http/https protocol  . The http/https protocol Stipulates a series headers. use that. don't take the key what you customized.

Comment: if not, the firewall maybe remove the header what not in the protocol stipulates